# Crystal Report Chart not showing with big data load

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report

I am stacked for two days with that issue.
I have a crystal report containing a chart that load big data from sql server more than 48 000 repords or let's say 48 000 xaxis points should be displayed but the problem is that chart is not showing. It just give an empty bordered rectangle.
I put the chart in the report header.
I tried to make many changes for the xaxis in the chart export but no result and the problem persist...
I am using Crsytal Reports XI and I tried on crystal reports for vs2010
Please any help will be appreciated

Comment: Ok, some more info would be useful. What should the chart display? How is your report structured? Can you post a screenshot of the report somewhere and link to it? Have you tried limiting your records (Record Select), does the chart show anything then? What happens if you move the chart to a different section of the report?

Comment: The chart should display in its Xaxis numbers from 1 to 46000 and in its Yaxis value between -300 and +300.
The report is formed from report header , page header , group header, details, group footer, page footer, report footer .
I put the chart in group header section and in the report section but nothing happens in both case.
Yes I tried to limit the record in my stored procedure then the chart displays normally.

Comment: So that means that the chart is unable to show the large amount of records. Any chance you can get away with showing less data in your chart, like only every 3rd record or so?